# How do I use Lightning EarPods with MacBook Pro 2015?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, iphone

The EarPods which come with iPhone 7 are Lightning EarPods, there isn't a Female Lightning to Male 3.5mm connector in the market AFAIK. The cable which Apple gives along with iPhone 7 is Male Lightning to Female 3.5mm connector.

Is there any way I can use the Lightning EarPods with my MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 3):

**You can't.**

Yes, it is a design flaw. You will need to buy regular earbuds that use the 3.5mm connector. If you want to use these headphones with your iphone, you will need to use the 3.5mm to lightning adapted that was on the back of your earpod case.